# Is there any way to block apps on windows 10 from using internet

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10

I have hp laptop with windows 10 and whenever i connect it to the internet all apps start using internet as shown in attachment.
Example NVidia Backend, Microsoft update, service host local system.

Is there any way to stop them and allow selected apps to use internet.
Like nowadays,i only want google chrome and eagleget to use internet.

Thanks

Comment: You can specify that you are on a "metered connection", but I'm not sure what are the behavior changes.

Comment: Either get a proper, more aggressive third-party firewall or block each and every application through Windows firewall rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tutorial from [SimpleHelp.net](http://www.simplehelp.net/2015/09/02/how-to-block-a-program-from-the-internet-in-windows-10/):

> This tutorial will take you every single step of the way through
>   creating a Windows Firewall Rule to block a specific program
>   (whichever you want) in Windows 10.
>
> Start out by clicking the Windows 10 Start Button and in the Search
>   section type the word firewall. One of the items that will be
>   displayed is Windows Firewall | Control Panel. Select that one.
>
> [image: 1]
>
> You’ll be presented with the main Windows 10 Firewall screen.
>
> [image: 2]
>
> From the column on the left side of the window, click the Advanced
>   Settings… item.
>
> [image: 3]
>
> Now you’ll be presented with the Advanced section of the Windows 10
>   Firewall.
>
> [image]
>
> Select the Outbound Rules item from the left-most column.
>
> [image: 5]
>
> Now you’ll be presented with the Advanced Outbound Rules section.
>
> [image: 6]
>
> This time we’re going to look in the column on the right side of the
>   screen, titled Outbound Rules…. From this section, select New Rule…
>
> [image: 7]
>
> When asked which type of connection you want to block, select Program
>   and then click the Next > button.
>
> [image: 8]
>
> Since you only want to block one program (not them all) – click the
>   Browse… button next to This program path:. NOTE: you can of course
>   block more than one program by creating multiple rules.
>
> [image: 9]
>
> Click through the folders on your PC until you find the Application
>   you want to block from accessing the Internet. If you’re having
>   trouble locating it, it’s probably in the Program Files folder, likely
>   in a sub-folder with either the program name or company name as a part
>   of the folder name itself. When you’ve found it, select it by clicking
>   on it once, and then click the Open button.
>
> [image: 10]
>
> Click the Next > button to continue.
>
> [image: 11]
>
> Select Block the connection and then click the Next > button.
>
> [image: 12]
>
> Make sure that all three items (Domain, Private and Public) have
>   “check marks” next to them, and then click the Next > button.
>
> [image: 13]
>
> Give your newly created “rule” a name and quick description, and
>   finally, click the Finish button.
>
> [image: 14]
>
> You’ll be returned to the Advanced Outbound Windows Firewall Settings
>   section.
>
> [image: 15]
>
> This time, the column on the right side (Actions) will have your newly
>   created Rule in it!
>
> [image: 16]
>
> As stated earlier in this tutorial, you can do this for as many
>   programs in Windows 10 as you’d like. You can even use the “Copy”
>   button to create similar rules without having to go through every step
>   again.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). 
You should block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).
I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.